# How do I set the Hibernate dialect in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire

I have a custom dialect to set for Hibernate in SpringBoot.  The dialect is for Gemfire. The [instructions](https://discuss.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201724017-Pivotal-GemFire-XD-Hibernate-Dialect) are for XML-based config.

However, I am using SpringBoot and I cannot figure out how to set this property.

The dialect is `com.pivotal.gemfirexd.hibernate.GemFireXDDialect`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = com.pivotal.gemfirexd.hibernate.GemFireXDDialect
```

Comment: I am using `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect`, but Hibernate ignores it, does not invoke `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier.render(Dialect)`, and instead invokes `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier.render()`, so I am getting ticks in place of double quotes.

Answer (score 25):

You can use this approach as well:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=com.pivotal.gemfirexd.hibernate.GemFireXDDialect
```

Answer (score 11):

Yet another way to set the dialect is via the `spring.jpa.database` property using a short DB name (case insensitive) as defined in the [db vendors list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.html). For example:

```
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use this for activating oracle 10 g dialect

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

#For MySQL database :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

you can check this format :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= com.pivotal.gemfirexd.hibernate.GemFireXDDialect
```