# Getting org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type:

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm creating a spring boot application with few many to many relations between 3 entities. The entities are `Course`, `Program` and `Major`.

Now `Course` has list of both `Program` and `Major` (both Many to Many). Also `Major` has list of 'Program' (also Many to Many).

Following is my postgresql configuration file:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rootdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

following is my `Course` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "course_code")
   private String courseCode;

   //other fields

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    @JoinTable(name = "course_major", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
 "course_code", referencedColumnName = "course_code"), inverseJoinColumns =   
    @JoinColumn(name = "major_uid", referencedColumnName = "major_uid"))

    private Set<Major> majors;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    @JoinTable(name = "course_program", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"course_code", referencedColumnName = "course_code"), inverseJoinColumns = 
 @JoinColumn(name = "program_uid", referencedColumnName = "program_uid"))

    private Set<Program> programs;

    //getter-setters
}
```

Following in my `Major` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "major")
public class Major extends BaseAuditingEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "major_uid")
    private String uid;

    //other fields

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "majors")
    private Set<Course> courses;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

    @JoinTable(name = "program_major", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "major_uid", referencedColumnName = "major_uid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_uid", referencedColumnName = "program_uid"))

    private Set<Program> programs;

    //getter-setters

}
```

And following is my `Program` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "program")
public class Program extends BaseAuditingEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "program_uid")
    private String uid;     

    //other fields 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "programs")
    private Set<Course> courses;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "programs")
    private Set<Major> majors; 

    //getter-setters
}
```

And the complete error log is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 

with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.toyota.aftersales.pqss.tten.courseservice.Application.main(Application.java:32)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1589370464
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlCreateString(Table.java:512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript(Configuration.java:1071)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:517)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
2018-03-21 12:09:23 [main] INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener -
                Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/Documents/course-mgmt-service/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Crest/Documents/pqss_shared/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.0.Final/validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson-xml-databind/0.6.2/jackson-xml-databind-0.6.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.2/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.2/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.2/jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.0/stax2-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/perf4j/perf4j/0.9.16/perf4j-0.9.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.9/aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/commons-jexl/commons-jexl/1.1/commons-jexl-1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/asm/asm/1.5.3/asm-1.5.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.1_3/cglib-2.1_3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/Documents/tten-commons/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.7.0/springfox-swagger2-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.13/swagger-annotations-1.5.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.13/swagger-models-1.5.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.7.0/springfox-spi-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.7.0/springfox-core-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.6.14/byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.7.0/springfox-schema-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.7.0/springfox-swagger-common-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.7.0/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.11/reflections-0.9.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.1.0.Final/mapstruct-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.0.0/json-path-2.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.1.1/json-smart-2.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/net/minidev/asm/1.0.2/asm-1.0.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.7.0/springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/net/sf/dozer/dozer/5.5.1/dozer-5.5.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901-1.jdbc4/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.33/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.10.10.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.12.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.12.10.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-test-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Crest/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar]
```

So what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

I've also referred some same threads on SO, like this: [No Dialect mapping for JDBC type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052059/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type)

but no my error code is different then all other errors mentioned.

**EDIT**

```
#server.name=logs
#application.log.path=${user.dir}
#service.name=@project.name@

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rootdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
server.port=7002
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
spring.jpa.database-platform= postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.toyota.aftersales.tten</groupId>
    <artifactId>tten-common</artifactId>
    <version>v0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!--API Documentation -->
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Used in Internal compiler path for testing with MockMvc -->
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!--User interface for API Documentation -->
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Dozer for map classes -->
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Dependency list:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    net.minidev:asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]    net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.5.1:compile
[INFO]    org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.14.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO]    org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO]    net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO]    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO]    io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO]    javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO]    org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO]    postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581074/how-do-i-set-the-hibernate-dialect-in-springboot . Setting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect will do the work

Comment: already tried @NisheethShah

Comment: Can you post your dependencies from your pom or gradle file?

Comment: yes sure. see the updates

Comment: You got to change the postgresql dependency. Try this one
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: still not working

Comment: Showing same error?

Comment: yes still same error

Comment: I implemented using the same properties and dependencies, and used latest postgresql dependencies. It is working fine for me. I would suggest you to use spring boot dependencies management to avoid version problems.

Comment: I still can see the older version of postgresql. [INFO]    postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4:compile.

Answer (score 0):

Add few more property, Try by replacing this

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

to

spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

spring.jpa.database-platform= postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

**Edited**

```
  spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
    spring.datasource.platform=postgres
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    #spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rootdb
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=123
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
    server.port=7002
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
    #spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Comment: It gives error at spring.datasource.platform.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

Comment: yes. right!!. that is my bad. it is spring.datasource.type

Comment: now error changed: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource]]`

Comment: with too many nested exceptions. If you want I'll post full error log

Comment: spring.datasource.type is optional. try without this property. because you need its library. if you don't want then you can avoid it

Comment: now `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2105339048` again same error with diff. error code

Comment: Which final file?

Comment: postgresql configuration

Comment: I think this error is because of datatype missmatch between java and postgresql. But I'm not being able to find out where

Comment: `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1953069155` same error with your updated file also.